# Pivoting a table with duplicate index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, reshape

I wanted to pivot this table:

```
    Year    County  Sex     rate
0   2006    Alameda Male    45.80
1   2006    Alameda Female  54.20
2   2006    Alpine  Male    52.81
3   2006    Alpine  Female  47.19
4   2006    Amador  Male    49.97
5   2006    Amador  female  50.30
```

My desired output is:

```
Year    County  Male  Female
2006    Alameda 45.80 54.20
2006    Alameda 52.81 47.19
2006    Alpine  49.97 50.30
```

I tried doing this:

```
sex_rate=g.pivot(index="County",columns='Year',values='rate')
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Please help. I am new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `index=['Year', 'County']`, not just `index='County'`. And since you are passing two columns to `index`, you may want to use `pivot_table` instead of `pivot`:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Year','County'], 
               columns='Sex', values='rate'
              ).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Sex  Year   County  Female   Male
0    2006  Alameda   54.20  45.80
1    2006   Alpine   47.19  52.81
2    2006   Amador   50.30  49.97
```

Comment: Amazing...Thank you!